# How to save the subtracted value from span to cookie till checkbox unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this bit of code which carries some numeric values within the span but when u click on checkbox it subtract 1 from the main value, basically it subtracts 1 from the total value, how to achieve this even if the form is submitted the deducted value in span remains same unless the checkbox is unchecked?

HTML is here with 10 for example value:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="featured" name="featured" <?php echo $checked;?> /> (<span id="credit">10</span>)
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#featured').change(function () {
    var currentValue = parseInt($('#credit').text());
    var newValue = currentValue + ($(this).prop('checked') ? -1 : 1);
    $('#credit').text(newValue);
  });
});
</script>
```

Your time and help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"basically it subtracts 1 from the total, how to achieve this even if the form is submitted the deducted value in span remains same unless the checkbox is unchecked?"_... what?

Comment: as of now default value for example is 10 right? whats happening now is when i check the checkbox the value does becomes 9 but on submit of form the checkbox remains checked but the default 10 goes back to 10 again and when i uncheck the box it becomes 11 instead

Comment: Then you need to inject the remaining value into the span with PHP, right? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: what i want it even after form submit the value which is 9 on check remains 9 until checkbox is cleared

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#featured').change(function () {
    var savedValue = localStorage.checkboxValue;
    var currentValue = savedValue ? parseInt(savedValue) : parseInt($('#credit').text());
    var newValue = currentValue + ($(this).prop('checked') ? -1 : 1);
    $('#credit').text(newValue);
    localStorage.checkboxValue = newValue;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: dont seem to be working made after submitting form the value goes back to 10 and when uncheck the box it now becomes 91 :D

Comment: Yeah I didn't test that code at all or really try to tweak your logic.  The idea is to save the checkbox value to local storage.  At the beginning of the code check if the value exists in local storage.  If so, use it, if not, use the default.  At the end save the new value. EDIT: I didn't use parseInt on savedValue